# Peapod: Impl is not abstract and does not override abstract method start() in peapod.FramedVertexTraversal

Tags: java, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

Started off with some basic tinkering to create a domainmodel.
I got Titan running, added its graph of the gods and used gremlin to traverse it succesfully.

But when i try to create a `FramedGraph` i get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at peapod.internal.runtime.FramerRegistry.lambda$register$1(FramerRegistry.java:47)
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at peapod.internal.runtime.FramerRegistry.register(FramerRegistry.java:45)
at peapod.FramedGraph.<init>(FramedGraph.java:73)
at my.domain.model.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - my.domain.model.vertices.Person$Impl is not abstract and does not override abstract method start() in peapod.FramedVertexTraversal
at my.domain.model.vertices.Person$Impl$PersonFramer.<clinit>(Person$Impl.java:14)
... 10 more
```

Here is my script:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("--- Creating Titan client ---");
    TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open("path/to/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1/conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties");
    //GraphTraversalSource gremlin = graph.traversal();
    System.out.println("--- Creating FramedGraph ---");
    try {
        FramedGraph g = new FramedGraph(graph, Package.getPackage("my.domain.model"));

        //GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(graph);
        //Vertex saturn = gremlin.V().has("name", "saturn").next();
        //System.out.println(saturn.value("name"));
        System.out.println("--- Creating Person Vertex and adding it to the graph ---");
        Person person = g.addVertex(Person.class);
        System.out.println("--- Setting its name ---");
        person.setName("alice");

        System.out.println("--- Retriving all Persons with name ---");
        List<Person> persons = g.V(Person.class).has("name", "alice").toList();

        assert 1 == persons.size() : "More than one Person vertex found.";

        g.close();
    } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 

    graph.close();
}
```

My abstract Person class:

```
package my.domain.model.vertices;

import peapod.annotations.Vertex;

@Vertex
public abstract class Person{
  public abstract String getName();
  public abstract void setName(String name);
}
```

I am using `Titan 1.0.0 Hadoop1`, maybe its a version issue since peapod uses `Tinkerpop 3.0.0.M9-incubating` and titan seems to use `Tinkerpop 3.0.1-incubating`

Comment: It's not a version issue for sure. I have Peapod running nicely with Titan 1.0 in a project. My guess is something went wrong during Which Peapod version are you using? Does your code work when you switch to version `0.2.2`? Do you use Maven?

Comment: Hmmm, weird. I ran into another issue after forcing Java8 and got it out of the way by going back to titan 0.9.0-M2, since some titan class threw a ClassNotFoundException. Yes I am using maven and Peapod 0.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Willem from Peapod. I tested your classes.

Peapod needs Java 8 and uses default methods defined in interface classes. Be sure to compile with Java 8 compatability.

Add this to your maven pom.xml file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it still did not work afterwards. This time there were version issues, but i managed to get it to work with `Titan 0.9.0.M2`